# Randomly Generate a Word from a txt.file (Python)

Tags: python

I have a text file of sentences. I need to randomly read strings and output the string and its line number in an output file. I have written the following code:

```
ifile = open("test2.txt", "r")
otfile = open("OUT3.txt", "w")
otfile.write("Randomly Selected String \t\t\t Line Number")

import random 

i=0

for lines in ifile.readline():

  line = lines[i] 

  words = line.split() 
  myword = random.choice(words)

  otfile.write(myword)
  otfile.write(str(i))
  i +=1
  otfile.write("\n")
```

However I am only getting one character and no line number. I have been trying to change the code but I am just creating errors. Any ideas?

(Edit)
Test2.txt has the following sentences:

```
Brooklyn is the best place on Earth.
I had chocolate ice cream today.
I ate all the cookies in the cookie jar.
Today was a no good very bad day.
He got his clothes dirty playing outside.
```

Comment: The contents of `test2.txt` would be helpful.

Comment: @Vallentin sorry about that, just edited the post with the contents.

Comment: does the code compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually incrementing `i`, you could use `enumerate()`. The problem with your code is that you do `line = lines[i]`. You're taking the character at `i` position and assigning it to `line`.

```
for i, line in enumerate(ifile.readlines(), start=1):
    words = line.split()
    myword = random.choice(words)

    otfile.write("Line: %d - Word: %s\n" % (i, myword))
```

The output of course changes due to the randomness. However a run could yield:

```
Line: 1 - Word: the
Line: 2 - Word: chocolate
Line: 3 - Word: I
Line: 4 - Word: was
Line: 5 - Word: clothes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the source of your bug:

```
for lines in ifile.readline():
    line = lines[i]
```

There are several aspects of your code that you could clean up. The problem is that you are iterating over *a single line* of a textfile in your for-loop, i.e. the value of `ifile.readline()` is a string! So when you do:

```
for lines in ifile.readline():
```

The looping variable `lines` is iterating over individual characters of the first line of the file. I'm not sure what you intended by:

```
line = lines[i]
```

But I would just delete it. You can iterate over file-handlers directly, line by line, simply by using a for-loop:

```
f = open('my_file.txt')

for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    < do something with words >
```

In addition, I should point out again there are several aspect to your code that should be addressed. The use of `enumerate` instead of explicitely keeping track of the index variable `i`is one potential improvement as is the use of the `with` statement to open files. Your code should probably start something like this:

```
with open("test2.txt", "r") as ifile, open("OUT3.txt", "w") as otfile:
    otfile.write("Randomly Selected String \t\t\t Line Number")

    for i, line in enumerate(ifile):
        <do stuff with line and line number i>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1
for lines in ifile:
  print(lines)
  words = lines.strip().split()
  print(words)
  myword = random.choice(words)
  print(myword[random.randrange(0, len(myword))])
  myword = myword[random.randrange(0, len(myword))]  # chr , need str Comment this line
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
with open('test2.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split(' ')
        myword = random.choice([x for x in words])
        print ">"+str(myword)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution! Added a counter that counts the number of lines and outputs the count as lines.

```
ifile = open("text2.txt", "r")
otfile = open("OUT3.txt", "w")
otfile.write("")
lst = []
import random
count = 1 # count the number of lines. Starts at 1.
for lines in ifile.readlines():
   words = lines.split()
   lst.extend(words) # add all the words to a list using .extend method
   myword = random.choice(lst)
   otfile.write("Line:{} Word: {} ".format(count, myword))
   count += 1
```

Out: `Line:1 Word: the Line:2 Word: icecream Line:3 Word: chocolate Line:4 Word: the Line:5 Word: today. Line:6 Word: bad`